# Angular change flex direction when Wrapper is small

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

Is it possible with Angular flex-layout apply responsive api on wrappers not on whole screen?

If I have code:

```
<div class="main-wrapper" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row" >
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div2</div>
</div>
```

Flex direction will change only when whole screen is smaller. Is there any way how to change flex dirrection when `main-wrapper` is small, not the screen?

If not with flex layout, is it possible to do it with css?

Answer (score 0):

There's **no way** to do what you would like to do. The best that you can do is set your custom breakpoint as said in the official GitHub project **[here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Custom-Breakpoints)**.